# SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' by just copying to another project

Tags: python, python-3.x

I got this error after copying the content to another project:

```
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file ***/PostToIn.py on line 81, but no encoding declared;
see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

The content's code is:

```
exp = "9 √ 3 ="
```

This SyntaxError still popped up even though I commented this line as the following:

```
# exp = "9 √ 3 ="
```

But the same line in the original project could run smoothly without any error.

What's the matter, please?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you read [PEP 263](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/), the page indicated in the error message?

Comment: Did you copy it from a Python 3 project to a Python 2 project, or unintentionally run your project under Python 2? Python 3 doesn’t have this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string you have there has a non-ascii character `√` which python can't parse. The solution is to replace it with `\xe2` which will then expand to `√` when the code runs. So the fixed code should look like this:

```py
exp = u"9 \xe2 3 ="
```

The other solution is to tell python the string you have is actually UTF-8 by prefixing it with a u.

```py
exp = u"9 √ 3 ="
```

Comment: But why in another project could the same line run without any problem? In addition, I followed your suggestion to replace it with \xe2, it could run without this error, but the result is weird: �=3, not the normal result: √9=3.

Comment: You will run into this issue with python 2 since it uses ASCII strings by default. Python 3 uses Unicode by default. Make sure you have your IDE configured to use the correct version of python for your use case.

Comment: `\x` is special because it turns turns the number directly after it into a Unicode character. If you don't have a seperator before the `9`, it will try to use Unicode character `U+E29` instead of `U+E2`. According to google, the character it is trying to display is http://unicode.scarfboy.com/?s=U%2B0e29, but I doubt the font used in your terminal knows how to display it.

Comment: Thank you very much! I chose Python 3 as the Python Interpreter as creating the new project, but the IDE changed it to 2.7 automatically. I don't know why. Now I have changed it to Python 3 in the project, and it could run without this error.